# Forcing username refresh on login angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have got a navbar in the header component which is shared on all routes. 
I want the current user's username to be shown on the navbar when he is logged in. I've got this working but currently after the user logs in I have to manually refresh the page before the username appears.

The login system is token based in my app. When the user logs in the username and token are saved in local storage. I can check that this happens after the login but as the header does not need to refresh at login it doesn't show the user name. If I reload the page after login the header shows the username correctly.

How can I force the header component to get the username from the auth service when the user logs in?

From the header component --

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  private currentUser: User;

  constructor(
    public auth:AuthService,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) { 
    this.currentUser = auth.getCurrentUserName();
  }
  ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

Auth service ..

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public token: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

public getCurrentUserId(){
     if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')){
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).id;
     } else return "";
   }
```

Comment: The usual way would be to subscribe to some form of notification/observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was to use the function from auth service directly in my template instead of setting a local variable first.

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown ">
          <button id="navbarDropdown" role="button">
            {{auth.getCurrentUserName()}}
          </button>
          ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use an Observable:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
private _currentUser: BehaviorSubject<string>;

constructor() {
    this._currentUser = new BehaviorSubject("");
}

getCurrentUser(): Observable<string> {
    return this._currentUser.asObservable();
}

setUser(user: string) {
    this._currentUser.next(user);
}
```

and your component would be something like this:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
private currentUser: User;

constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    private alertService: AlertService
) {
    this.currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser()
        .subscribe(user => this.currentUser = user);
}
ngOnInit() {

}
}
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why this would be better than what I am doing?